# Find all windows beneath a point

Tags: windows, winapi

I want to find all the top-level windows (children of the desktop) beneath a given point on the desktop. I can't find an API for this.

My scenario is that I'm dragging a window across the screen and want to drop it into another (known) window. I can hit test the bounds of the target window ok, but that doesn't tell me whether it's occluded by another (unknown) window. Using `WindowFromPoint` and friends won't work, because the window being dragged is necessarily directly under the mouse. So I'm wondering if I can obtain all windows at the mouse position, and review them to see whether one of the windows I'm tracking is directly beneath the window I'm dragging.

Is there a way to do this without resorting to `EnumDesktopWindows`/`GetWindowRect` on every mouse drag? Or perhaps there's another solution I'm missing.

Comment: If you make the assumption that no new windows will be created while you're dragging, you can enumerate the top-level windows once at the start of the drag operation, and then use the result to test against at every mouse move during the drag.

Comment: That's an optimisation worth investigating, thanks.

Comment: You might be able to get away with using `GetNextWindow` and just looking at the windows above your target in the Z Order.

Comment: @theB, thanks, that sounds quite promising too!

Comment: @JimMischel: you are assuming that other windows are not being moved around by their own app while the user is dragging the desired window.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, that's true. Probably a bad assumption on my part.

Comment: @theB, MSDN made an interesting observation about calling `GetNextWindow` in a loop: The `EnumChildWindows` function is more reliable than calling `GetWindow` in a loop. An application that calls `GetWindow` to perform this task risks being caught in an infinite loop or referencing a handle to a window that has been destroyed.

Comment: I'd say that you are trying to solve this problem the wrong way around. In other words, this might be an XY question. Instead of the window being dragged deciding whether it can be dropped, the *destination* should decide if it is a drop target for the object being dragged. That way, the window being dragged isn't responsible for hit-testing and interrogating all objects that it passes over; rather, each object that it passes over (assuming it is drag-drop-aware) is responsible for deciding whether it can accept that object. Use the `RegisterDragDrop` function for this.

Comment: A nice tutorial is available here: http://www.catch22.net/tuts/drop-target

Comment: @CodyGray you're right that it's a bit backwards. The problem stems from the fact that the dragged window remains under the mouse which obscures the drop behaviour. I actually want the window to be dragged too. The target window doesn't receive any events as far as I can tell.

Comment: @DrewNoakes EnumChildWindow seems for child windows only while GetNextWindow considers more than children.

Comment: Chrome seems to do exactly what you want (when you drag a tab from one Chrome frame to another), but Spy++ doesn't give many hints.  Visual Studio, creates TOPMOST drop target windows, and I suspect those are found by WindowFromPoint since they remain above the window being dragged.

Comment: Why do you need to find all window under the cursor for *every mouse position*? Just do it once when you release the button.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε, to give feedback during dragging. Whether I do it throughout or at the end, I still have a problem (see question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you ask kindly, `WindowFromPoint` will ignore your window (the one currently being dragged) and return the next window. This is what Internet Explorer does when you drag a tab.

**To do that:**

1. Handle `WM_NCHITTEST` in window being dragged
2. Return `HTTRANSPARENT` during dragging. Call default window proc otherwise.
3. `WindowFromPoint` [will ignore](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101230-00/?p=11873) `HTTRANSPARENT` windows, but only those belonging to the calling thread. This shouldn't be a problem for you, because you should be calling `WindowFromPoint` from the window owner thread anyway.
4. Make sure there're no child windows at point passed to `WindowFromPoint`, or handle `WM_NCHITTEST` for these child windows as well.

**Troubleshooting** (if you still get your window from `WindowFromPoint`)

1. Test `GetCurrentThreadID() == GetWindowThreadProcessId(WindowFromPoint(), 0)` to ensure you're calling from correct thread
2. In `WM_NCHITTEST`, test that `hwnd` parameter equals what you get from `WindowFromPoint()`

**Example** (the area within rectangle returns the underlying window from `WindowFromPoint`):

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static const RECT s_TransparentRect = {100, 100, 200, 200};

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_NCCREATE:
        SetTimer(hWnd, 1, 100, 0);
        break;
    case WM_TIMER:
        {
            POINT cursorPos;
            GetCursorPos(&cursorPos);

            TCHAR buffer[256];
            _snwprintf_s(buffer, _countof(buffer), _TRUNCATE, _T("WindowFromPoint: %08X\n"), (int)WindowFromPoint(cursorPos));
            SetWindowText(hWnd, buffer);
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            Rectangle(ps.hdc, s_TransparentRect.left, s_TransparentRect.top, s_TransparentRect.right, s_TransparentRect.bottom);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_NCHITTEST:
        {
            POINT cursorPos;
            GetCursorPos(&cursorPos);
            MapWindowPoints(HWND_DESKTOP, hWnd, &cursorPos, 1);

            if (PtInRect(&s_TransparentRect, cursorPos))
                return HTTRANSPARENT;
        }
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This promises to avoid repeated (linear in number of top-level windows) API calls. Will experiment and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks again. With some experimentation this turned out quite well.

Comment: Did you need any extra steps I didn't mention?

Comment: And you're welcome, that was an interesting question to investigate.

Comment: @Codeguard Will this technique work if the drag is occurring using a standard title bar (i.e., the non-client area)?

Comment: I expect that yes, but just give it a try.

Comment: @Codeguard I've tried it out but can't get it to work.  Would you mind checking out my question here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/68701511/15284017

Answer (score 4):

Right, you already know what WindowFromPoint() is going to return, should be the one you are dragging.  Then use [GetWindow()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633515(v=vs.85).aspx) with uCmd = GW_HWNDNEXT to get the one below it in the Z-order.  GetWindowRect() to get its bounds, IntersectRect() to compute the overlap.

Keep calling GetWindow() to find more windows that might be overlapped.  Until it returns NULL or the overlap is good enough.  If not then you'll normally favor the one that has the largest result rectangle from IntersectRect().

Comment: Took this for a spin and found that hit testing the rectangle is not enough. There are loads of windows on the desktop that get picked up, even though they're not visible from the user's perspective. For example, a window with title `AXWIN Frame Window` appears, having innocent enough (ex)styles. Is there some other means of testing visibility? Testing the rectangle can also fail for layered windows.

Comment: Add a test on IsWindowVisible()

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work well. Scanning on my machine runs sub-millisecond, which is great. Still it fails for layered windows having transparent regions.