# WindowFromPoint doesn't trigger WM_NCHITTEST when window is being dragged

Tags: c++, winapi, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to follow the instructions provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40813244/15284017) answer in order to find the window beneath a point, *aside* from a window that's currently being dragged.

The problem with my attempt is that when calling `WindowFromPoint` during the drag operation, the `WM_NCHITTEST` message is apparently not being triggered. And so the entire thing doesn't work, and I can't obtain the window underneath the one being dragged.

Here is a minimal reproducible example.  If you run this and drag one of the windows by its title bar, you'll notice that "OnNcHitTest" is not displayed to the debug console, even though `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` is being handled and `WindowFromPoint` is being called.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlwin.h>
#include <atltypes.h>

using namespace ATL;

class CMyWindow :
    public CWindowImpl<CMyWindow, CWindow, CWinTraits<WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME, WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW>>
{
public:
    CMyWindow() : m_fDragging(FALSE)
    {
    }

BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CMyWindow)
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED, OnWindowPosChanged)
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_NCHITTEST, OnNcHitTest)
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_EXITSIZEMOVE, OnExitSizeMove)
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_SYSCOMMAND, OnSysCommand)
    COMMAND_HANDLER(IDCANCEL, BN_CLICKED, OnClickedCancel)
END_MSG_MAP()

private:
    LRESULT OnSysCommand(UINT, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        bHandled = FALSE;

        if ((wParam & 0xFFF0) == SC_MOVE)
        {
            m_fDragging = TRUE;
            ATLTRACE(L"\nDrag begin\n");
        }
            
        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnExitSizeMove(UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        bHandled = FALSE;
        
        m_fDragging = FALSE;
        ATLTRACE(L"\nDrag end\n");
        
        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnNcHitTest(UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        ATLTRACE(L"\nOnNcHitTest\n");
        
        if (m_fDragging)
            return HTTRANSPARENT;

        bHandled = FALSE;
        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnWindowPosChanged(UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        ATLTRACE(L"\nOnWindowPosChanged\n");
        
        bHandled = FALSE;

        if (m_fDragging)
        {
            CPoint pt;
            if (GetCursorPos(&pt))
            {
                ATLTRACE(L"\nCalling WindowFromPoint\n");
                HWND hwndFromPoint = WindowFromPoint(pt);
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnClickedCancel(WORD, WORD, HWND, BOOL&)
    {
        DestroyWindow();
        return 0;
    }

    void OnFinalMessage(HWND)
    {
        delete this;
    }

    BOOL m_fDragging;
};

INT APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPWSTR, INT)
{
    for (UINT i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        CMyWindow* pwnd = new CMyWindow();
        if (pwnd)
        {
            CRect rc(0, 0, 500, 500);
            if (pwnd->Create(NULL, &rc))
            {
                pwnd->CenterWindow(NULL);
                pwnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
            }
        }
    }

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (INT)msg.wParam;
}
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?  Does this have to do with the move/size modal loop or something?  I wouldn't think that's the problem, because as long as `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` is being triggered and `WindowFromPoint` is being called, then I would think `WM_NCHITTEST` would be sent.  But maybe I'm wrong.

Or does the issue have to do with the mouse being in a non-client area perhaps?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand WHY the window being dragged would be sent `WM_NCHITTEST` message... Obviously, the result would be  `HTCAPTION`, or it wouldn't be dragged.

Comment: So how is the linked answer supposed to work then?

Comment: Will wait for the author to answer...

Answer (score 0):

I made a change in `OnNcHitTest` to allow dragging by any point in the client area:

```
LRESULT OnNcHitTest(UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM, BOOL& bHandled)
{
    ATLTRACE(L"\nOnNcHitTest\n");

    if (m_fDragging)
        return HTTRANSPARENT;
    else
        return HTCAPTION;

    bHandled = FALSE;
    return 0;
}
```

Now the `OnNcHitTest` is called during dragging *IF* you drag by anything but the caption. And you get different HWND handles. Don't know why there is the difference.

What exactly are you trying to achieve? Custom drag-and-drop?